# как сделать чтобы функция работала постоянно в фоне? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, telegram-bot, telebot

как сделать чтобы функция alarm работала постоянно в фоне? python

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types
import time
import sqlite3
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()

# конект к дб юзеров
conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db", check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE users (id int, balance int, transactions int, turnover int, ltc_rate_min int, ltc_rate_max int)""")
except:
    pass
conn.close()

# конект к дб покупок
conn = sqlite3.connect("buy.db", check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE buys (buy_id int, user_id int, sum int, sum_ltc real, status text)""")
except:
    pass
conn.close()

# получение курса LTC
def get_rate():
    while True:
        api = cg.get_price(ids='litecoin', vs_currencies='usd, rub')
        prices = api['litecoin']
        global rate_dollars
        global rate_rubbles
        rate_dollars = prices['usd']
        rate_rubbles = float(prices['rub'])
        time.sleep(30)

def alarm(message):
    while True:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db", check_same_thread=True)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?"
        tg_id = message.from_user.id
        cursor.execute(sql, [(tg_id)])
        n = cursor.fetchone()
        min = list(n)[4]
        max = list(n)[5]
        if min <= rate_dollars:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Курс ниже заданного минимума!')
        elif max >= rate_dollars:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Курс выше заданного максимума!')

        conn.close()

        time.sleep(300)

# токен
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
# если старт
def welcome(message):
    # подключение к дб
    conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db", check_same_thread=True)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?"
    tg_id = message.from_user.id
    cursor.execute(sql, [(tg_id)])
    # если пользователя нету в дб то добавляем
    if cursor.fetchone() is None:
        new_user = """INSERT INTO users VALUES ({0}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)"""
        tg_id = message.from_user.id
        cursor.execute(new_user.format(tg_id))
        conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    menu(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать потоки

```
from threading import Thread
t=Thread(target=alarm, args=(message, )) # передать переменную message. Обратите внимание на запятую после message!
t.start()
```