# Как сделать фоновую проверку условий в telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать так, чтобы бот постоянно проверял определенное условие в фоновом режиме, используя при этом `bot.polling(none_stop=True)` в основном режиме?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1279176/как-сделать-чтобы-функция-работала-постоянно-в-фоне-python

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140444/234134